# Copy List But Exclude Old Dates

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out, without any luck, how to copy an existing list, which is updated daily, from one sheet to another, but exclude dates older than `today()`.
I know how to look up specific dates via `VLookUp` or `Index Match`, but my goal is filter out an entire set of dates.
Here is a sample list which is updated daily through a set of formulas:

[image]

And the output on another sheet should look like this:

[image]

In this case excluding Feb 7th and Feb 10, since today's date is the 14th.
The number of entries in the original list can vary in length.

How can get this done without using VBA?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is housed in `A1:C17` (I'm including the *Los Angeles* title as well as the column header names), this formula should do the trick:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX((--($A$3:$A$17>=TODAY())*$A$3:$C$17),COUNT($A$3:$A$17)-COUNTIF($A$3:$A$17,">="&TODAY())+ROW(1:1),1),"")
```

Once you enter the formula, you can copy it to the remaining parts of your output table.

To do so, just change `...+ROW(1:1),1)...` to:

- `...+ROW(1:1),2)...` for the **Out** column, and
- `...+ROW(1:1),3)...` for the **In** column.

### [image]

It's a bit convoluted, but it seems to work. It operates based on the idea of arrays, but it isn't the kind of array formula you need to commit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which I usually find to be a bonus as it's easier to figure out what's wrong if something goes amiss.

Wrapping it all up nicely in an `IFERROR` allows you to weed out errors if you drag your output range past the point where data would return.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data like:

```
+---+-----------+
|   |     A     |
+---+-----------+
| 1 | 2/10/2017 |
| 2 | 2/13/2018 |
| 3 | 2/17/2017 |
| 4 | 2/15/2018 |
| 5 | 2/18/2018 |
| 6 | 2/19/2018 |
| 7 | 2/20/2018 |
| 8 | 2/28/2018 |
+---+-----------+
```

Then to get a list of dates that are greater than or equal to today, you could use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,(ROW()-1)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"<="&TODAY())), "")
```

And copy down.

To get the corresponding values from Column B, just change that range in `INDEX(<range>, ...` to Column B:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$8,(ROW()-1)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"<="&TODAY())), "")
```

*This is assuming your dates are sorted smallest to largest, otherwise this borks badly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. The dates do start from smallest to largest. I tried it out on the given sample in my post and on the new sheet I get the date 0-Jan, which isn't part of the list. This is what I used `=IFERROR(INDEX('DATA-PUs'!$J$3:$J$100,(ROW()-1)+COUNTIF('DATA-PUs'!$J$3:$J$100,"<="&TODAY())), "")`